# How can I add line breaks into my event title in json

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

one thing i can not get straight is the ability to add html without it being escaped or actually creating new lines

here's my json:

```
{ "id": 30,
  "title": "Basics \n  Awesome Abs & Butt Blast \n  Danielle B",
  "start": "2010-05-11T08:00:00-04:00",
  "end": "2010-05-11T08:30:00-04:00",
  "allDay": false
}
```

and here's the code for it:

```
[
  <% @events.each do |e| %>
        { "id": <%= e.id -%>,
        "title": "<p><%= e.event_template.level %></p><p><%= e.monqi_class.title %></p><p><%= e.instructor.last_initial %></p>",
            "start": "<%= e.start_date.iso8601 %>",
            "end": "<%= e.end_date.iso8601 %>",
            "allDay": false
         }
        <%= @events.last == e ? "" : ","  %>
    <% end -%>
]
```

so I am trying to have inside an even 3 lines, (level, class title, and instructor)

the problem is it's getting escaped so the charcters are not being parsed by html

can you please help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Ami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a token for a line-break, like `~` or `|`, then replace it with `<br />` on the output.

Comment: <br /> or styling on the CSS element are the only two ways I know to put a linebreak (hint: block). Is it a semantic break or a thematic break? (that determines where I would put it)

Answer (score 3):

discussion on the issue tracker regarding this topic. might help:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=351