# Invalid Json Error in JsonLint

Tags: json, jsonlint

I have a web service returning following json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "9469",
        "title": "A person grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was carrying a Ghanaian passport!",
        "introtext": "A person has grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian passport! 

An individual has gotten by police on the grounds that being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian visa! 

A 29-year-old Nigerian has been captured for endeavoring to get a visa with a falsely acquired Ghanaian travel permit."
    }
]
```

JSONLint is giving following error:

```
Parse error on line 5:
...       "introtext": "A person has grabbe
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I am really unable to understand what is making json invalid here? Is it newline or what? What can I do to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: I believe they are line breaks in your string

Answer (score 1):

New line present in introtex, this is valid json check it

```
         [
        {
            "id": "9469",
            "title": "A person grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was carrying a Ghanaian passport!",
            "introtext": "A person has grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian passport! An individual has gotten by police on the grounds that being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian visa! A 29-year-old Nigerian has been captured for endeavoring to get a visa with a falsely acquired Ghanaian travel permit."
        }
    ]
```

Comment: But I want linebreaks in my json. What should I do for it?

Comment: use \n when u need line break

Comment: @anum90 — Define "not working". I suspect that you are generating your JSON by manually mashing together strings in some programming language and the `\n` is being interpreted as a new line by that programming language and you are still outputting a literal new line in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Put your whole string in one line.
example

```
[
{
    "id": "9469",
    "title": "A person grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was carrying a Ghanaian passport!",
    "introtext": "A person has grabbed by police because being Nigerian he was having aGhanaian passport!  An individual has gotten by police on the grounds that being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian visa! A 29-year-old Nigerian has been captured for endeavoring to get a visa with a falsely acquired Ghanaian travel permit."
}
```

]

In case you want line break use

```
"introtext": "A person has grabbed by police because \n being Nigerian he was having aGhanaian passport!  An individual has gotten by police on the grounds that being Nigerian he was having a Ghanaian visa! A 29-year-old Nigerian has been captured for endeavoring to get a visa with a falsely acquired Ghanaian travel permit."
```

Comment: But I want linebreaks in my json. What should I do for it?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @MONTYHS and @AvinashGarg for pointing out the mistake. Newline is causing invalid JSON. To have break lines in my json, I am replacing all newline tags `<br/>` with a special character, e.g. `|~` (bar and a tilde). At client side, after parsing json, I replace occurrences of `|~` with `<br/>` back to display properly.

Hope it helps someone. Reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811983/437146).